# Saving cropped Video with opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I try to crop away the left most part of my video and save the processed video. The cv2.imshow part works fine but the saved file can't be played.
Thanks in advance!

```
import cv2


cap = cv2.VideoCapture('Vid.mov')
outcrop = cv2.VideoWriter('outcrop.mov', -1, 20.0, (640,480))

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    sky = frame[100:, 100:]
    cv2.imshow('Video', sky)
    outcrop.write(sky)         #I guess the problem lies in "(sky)" ??

    k = cv2.waitKey(5) & 0xFF
    if k == 27:
        break

cap.release()
outcrop.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: try to resize `sky` to `640x480`, try `sky = cv2.resize(sky, (640, 480))` and write it

Comment: Thanks alot ;) it worked. How do I mark your comment as "Answer for this question" ?

Comment: read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to resize sky to 640x480, try

```
sky = cv2.resize(sky, (640, 480))
```

and write it